# Remove Label in Else

Tags: tkinter, label, python-3.7

Very new with Python 3 and writing my first application in tkinter.

I have an if creating a Label when voucher(number) is out of range, max and min, however if I first run outside of the range and then change my number I would like to remove the Label in the beginning of my else code.

I have tried with `Label.delete`, `Label.destroy` but only throwing errors.

```
if int(voucher.get()) > int(maxN):
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)
    textbox.update()
    Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range").place(x=200, y=175)
    textbox.configure(state="disabled")

elif int(voucher.get()) < int(minN):
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)
    textbox.update()
    Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range").place(x=200, y=175)
    textbox.configure(state="disabled")

else:
    # I want to destroy Label here
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    Label(root, text="All well")
```

---

Any help is appreciated.

//Fred

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the labels but did not give each one a reference / label name. Without a reference you cannot tell the program which label to delete.

Instead of using:

```
Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range").place(x=200, y=175)
```

You must use (for example with the label Label1:):

```
Label1 = Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range")
Label1.place(x=200, y=175)
```

This will create a label with the reference/label name 'Label1'
Note: I put the .place() on the line below because when you put .place() on the same line like this:

```
Label1 = Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range").place(x=200, y=175)
```

The reference/ label Label1 is set to what is returned by:

```
Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of   valid range").place(x=200, y=175)
```

so it is set to none because .place() returns none.

To destroy a label (e.g. Label1) you use Label1.destroy().

Your improvedcode:

---

```
if int(voucher.get()) > int(maxN):
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)
    textbox.update()
    Label1 = Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range")
    Label1.place(x=200, y=175)
    textbox.configure(state="disabled")

elif int(voucher.get()) < int(minN):
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)
    textbox.update()
    Label1 = Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range")
    Label1.place(x=200, y=175)
    textbox.configure(state="disabled")

else:
    Label1.destroy()
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    Label2 = Label(root, text="All well")
    Label2.place(x=200, y=175)
```

---

I recommned you add:

```
if Label1.winfo_exists():
    Label1.destroy()
```

to your else statement, so that the Label1.destroy() code is only run of label 1 exists. This way, if label 1 was never created then the program doesnt attempt to destroy it.

This will make your else statement look like this:

```
else:
    if Label1.winfo_exists():
        Label1.destroy()
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    Label2 = Label(root, text="All well")
    Label2.place(x=200, y=175)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, both of you for your assistance, problem is solved, also had to also add:

global label5

Using:

if label5.winfo_exists():
    label5.destroy()

Was very useful.

//Fred

Answer (score 1):

It is throwing errors because you haven't assign any object to those Labels. If they don't have a reference how will the python know which Label needs to be destroyed.

`destroy()` is a method of `Label` class which you can't call just by `Label.destroy()` if haven't made an object to the class Label.

**For Example:**

```
L = Label(root, text="Hello World")
L.pack()

# Now, we can destroy it by

L.destroy()
```

---

Now your code as I don't know which label you want to delete so will take the first one you can change as pre your requirements.

```
if int(voucher.get()) > int(maxN):
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)
    textbox.update()
    L1 = Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range")
    L1.place(x=200, y=175)
    textbox.configure(state="disabled")

elif int(voucher.get()) < int(minN):
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    textbox.delete('1.0', END)
    textbox.update()
    L2 = Label(root, text="The voucher " + str(voucher.get()) + " number is outside of valid range")
    L2.place(x=200, y=175)
    textbox.configure(state="disabled")

else:
    L1.destroy()      # Label in if will destroy
    L2.destroy()      # Label in elif will destroy
    textbox.configure(state="normal")
    L3 = Label(root, text="All well")
```